# Integral strict inequality

Tags: integration

Assuming that $f \in C([0,1])$ and $f \geq 0$.

Does $$\int_0^1 fdx <1 \Leftrightarrow f<1$$ hold?

I know that $"\Leftarrow"$ holds as $1-f>0$. Is the other direction necessarily true?

Comment: If the average value of a nonnegative continuous function is less than $1,$ it does not mean that each value is less than $1.$ Take $f(x)={3\over 2}x.$ The integral is equal ${3\over 4}$ and the maximal value is equal ${3\over 2}.$

Answer (score 4):

No. For example $1-x^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$ does obtain the value $1$ at $0$, but: $$\int_0^1 1-x^2dx=\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $M > 1$, consider the continuous function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}M - M^2 x, & x \leq \frac{1}{M}\\ 0, & x > \frac{1}{M} \end{cases}
$$

The maximum value of $f$ is $M$ (which can be chosen as large as we want) but the integral is $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

Another obvious example is $f(x)=2-2\sqrt{x}$ where $f>1$ in a larger region.
$$\int_0^12-2\sqrt{x}\,dx=\frac{2}{3}$$